# Creating new Project in Rstuido puts it in ~ / This PC / Documents folder instead of directory specified in Global Options and

Tags: r, rstudio

- I just started learning R on Coursera.
- After installing RStudio, I created this directory to hold the new projects that I create: C:/dev/r
- I entered this directory path in Global Options / Default Working Directory (see below)
- However, when I create a new R project using the instructions in Coursera (see below), it has an option “Create project as a subdirectory of ~”
- If I just type in a project name and click “Create Project”, it creates it as a subdirectory of “This PC / Documents”
- I can explicitly replace “~” with “C:/dev/r” and it creates the project folder in the correct spot, but I don’t want to have to do that every single time I create a project
- In essence, can I “tell” RStudio that ~ = “c:/dev/r”, not “This PC / Documents”?

[image: r]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Project gets created successfully, But this directory gets created C:\Users{My Windows User Name}\Documents\MyProject**

[image]

Here is my .RHistory

```
getwd()
setwd("C:/dev/r")
dir
cd
?Startup
R_CHECK_ENVIRON
R_CHECK_ENVIRON()
candidates <- c( Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE"),
file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site"),
Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"),
file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile") )
Filter(file.exists, candidates)
file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile")
setwd("C:/dev/r")
getwd()
getwd()
getwd()
getwd()
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

And here is my Rprofile.site:

```
# Things you might want to change

# options(papersize="a4")
# options(editor="notepad")
# options(pager="internal")

# set the default help type
# options(help_type="text")
  options(help_type="html")

# set a site library
# .Library.site <- file.path(chartr("\\", "/", R.home()), "site-library")

# set a CRAN mirror
# local({r <- getOption("repos")
#       r["CRAN"] <- "http://my.local.cran"
#       options(repos=r)})

# Give a fortune cookie, but only to interactive sessions
# (This would need the fortunes package to be installed.)
#  if (interactive()) 
#    fortunes::fortune()
setwd("C:/dev/r")
```

Comment: My guess is that the default working directory (an R thing) doesn't get propagated to Rstudio's creating of new project interface. Perhaps if you assume these two are not identical it works as expected?

Comment: On my system (MacOS, not Windows), it appears to offer whatever I chose last time as the default.  So the first time I need to specify it, but after that they'll all go to the same place until I specify something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that it's because of the `create project as a subdirectory of` is specified as `~` not your working dir. The `~` is used to specify the home (user) directory on most systems. If you change the setup at creation so that it is pointing to your `working directory` then you shouldn't have any problems

Comment: I actually tried a complete reinstall of RStudio and I must have missed this option.  If I can't figure out another way to change it I'll try reinstalling again.  The reason i want to do this in the first place is that it was creating a new folder in "My Documents" for each and every project, and I'm a nut for keeping my files organized.  I also want the integration with GitHub to be smooth.  Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Man... I uninstalled using Windows add/remove programs, reinstalled, and it still creates the R directory in C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\R, and inside of that, "win-library".  When I create a project and leave ~ selected, it still creates a subdirectory for the project in C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\

Comment: That location is the default location and usually can't be easily changed in the install of any program (! not entirely true, some allow you to change location). I was meaning when you create the new project - just change the `~` to `dir\you\want`.

Comment: Thanks bob1.  I may just suck it up and live with the large number of subfolders in my "My Documents" directory.  I haven't gotten to the Coursera module yet on git integration so may it needs to be set like that in any case.  I'll also post a question in the Coursera community to see if anyone else has encountered this. Again, thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks again to everyone who helped me

Answer (score 0):

The location of `~` is set from (on Windows): `Sys.getenv("USERNAME")` See: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201751487-Sharing-a-Project-with-multiple-users . Since there's also a `Sys.setenv` function you may get to your goal by adjusting that environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.  Running the command "Sys.getenv("USERNAME")" in the RStudio console does indeed return my username: "MyFirstname.MyLastname".  I was able to run this command to set it correctly: Sys.setenv(USERNAME = "C:/dev/r").  However when I go through the same R project creation process above, it still creates the subfolder in My Documents

Comment: I think you'd need to set that before starting RStudio.  This page:  https://netlicensing.io/blog/2012/06/15/set-environment-variables-in-windows-shortcut/ shows how to do it for just one shortcut in Windows.

Comment: Did you try setting up a .Rprofile file?  I think may need to check with the Rstudio docs to find the right location. I’m not sure that the ?Startup page applies to Rstudio.

Comment: Hey, I just tried running this in PowerShell (before creating a shortcut/bat file) and it's throwing an error: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "SET USERNAME = "C:\dev\r".  I tried both directions on the "/", "\".  Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\dev\r

Comment: thank you 42, I'll find the .Rprofile (if it exists) and if not I'll google it and create one.